# Картинки с привязкой к записи

Tags: delphi, база-данных, firebird

Доброе время суток, форумчане.
У меня есть таблица птиц (*bird*), с их голосами (в таблице *service*), с полями:
id, field1 (integer), description (string), field2 (blob).
1   _____  234  ___________   voice    _______  mp3
2   _____ 234 ___________image_______     jpg             <- например

(честно говоря, названия полей не очень, т.к. в эту таблицу я скидывал все одиночные параметры, которые хранить не где)
До этого момента было все замечательно: пользователь становился на запись с птицей, просматривал ее характеристики, и если хотел нажимал кнопку (с динамиком), и отдельным запросом подкачивался голос.

Теперь к каждой птице, добавится ее одна или несколько картинок (или фото), скорее всего одна.
Картинка должна будет отображаться **всегда** (при перемещении по списку птиц), если она есть в БД.
 Теперь наверно придется делать все таки отдельную таблицу (н-р «features») с полями:
id, voice, image
т.е. таблицу с *id*, и двумя полями типа *blob* (*voice* и *image*), т.е. не т.к. в таблице *service*. А в табл. *bird*, поле с ссылкой на *id* в табл. *features*.

- Связку Master-detail – делать не хотелось бы (вытягивать все blob`ы в dataset), как-то не очень…
  Есть еще вариант:
- «в событии OnDataChange (TDataSource) написать запуск таймера с некоторой задержкой, много большей чем автоповтор клавиатуры. А уже по 
  срабатыванию этого таймера - загружать картинки, с помощью отдельного запроса, через какой-нибудь TIDQuery».
  **Вопрос**:
  -- Как будет правильнее поступить в этой ситуации?

Заранее **спасибо**.

P.S.
В табл. "bird", записей с одно й той же птицей может быть несколько (не спрашивайте почему)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> В табл. "bird", записей с одно й той же птицей может быть несколько (не спрашивайте почему)

Потому что не проведена [нормализация БД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0)

> Теперь наверно придется делать все таки отдельную таблицу (н-р «features») с полями:
>   id, voice, image

Можно же создать более универсальную таблицу в которой будет поля: **ID**, <**Тип данных**>(например: картинка, звук, описание...) , <**Данные**> (blob поле), <**Описание**>

> Связку Master-detail – делать не хотелось бы (вытягивать все blob`ы в dataset), как-то не очень…

А зачем загружать все данные? Вы можете вычитать список птиц, описания с таблицы где лежат картинки/звуки... И скажем при клике на описание  отображать картинку или воспроизводить звук.
Все зависит какая поставлена задача. 
Скорее всего придется грузить всегда первую картинку для отображения при "выборе птицы" , а потом по необходимости остальные.

Comment: Я возьму ваш вариант. Работа с одной таблицей - не будет, ли это потом **тормозить** работу БД, если скажем, к одной птице, добавиться несколько записей звука, и несколько фото?

Comment: Все зависит от многих факторов, к примеру количества данных и запросов которые вы напишите, где расположен сервер, насколько шустрый винчестер. Используете вы индексы или нет (последнее больше к поиску данных)